# Select a paragraph in Word and change its style

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to find if a line in my Word document starts with the word Picture, and if it does, change the Style of that line to a built in style. I believe a line that begins after a return key is interpreted by Word as new paragraph and the end of this paragraph is signified by another return key.

I have a single sentence paragraph, whose style I have to change if it begins with the word Picture. How can I search every line of the document to see if it begins with the word Picture?
--EDIT--
**I have changed the word Picture into Figure**
I'm trying to find all instances of figure and then convert the line containing figure into boldface (the boldface code will be replaced by code that changes style). For now I have skipped all error checks, and am trying to get it to find all instances of Figure and then convert the sentence characters into boldface, starting from the point where the word Figure is present.

```vb
Sub Macro1() 
' ' Macro1 Macro ' '  
     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting  
     Do  
     With Selection.Find  
         .Text = "figure"  
         .Forward = True  
         .Wrap = wdFindStop  
     End With  
     Selection.Find.Execute  
     Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend  
     Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle  
     Loop 
End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of the document
[image]
It just detects the first Figure in the line shown in the red circle.
I found the code keeps detecting the first instance of Figure from the current position of the insertion point over and over again.
How do I search for the next instance of Figure after detecting one of them?
Changing wdFindStop to wdFindContinue does not work; both produce the same result.

Comment: have you tried anything? you could start with macro recorder and 'find/search-replace` application feature... to be precise- should we worry if paragraph has 2 or more sentences? it's out of our interest? you could add screen shot to see part of document and result you search.

Comment: recording a macro that searches for the text Picture and then looking at it's source code shows that searching is probably done by selection.find.execute, followed by a With block which includes .text = "Picture". I am assuming this is how I can search for a particular text using macro code. But I need to select he whole sentence that begins with this word, which I am not sure how to do. I think I can manage changing the style though, if I can somehow select the correct sentence.

Comment: As I said before, this is a single sentence paragraph, and if the word Picture appears in the middle of some other paragraph, I need it to be ignored. I need to select the sentence containing the word Picture, only when this word starts the sentence

Comment: Is it possible to search for the word Picture, move the text insertion pointer to the beginning of the sentence, then select the text until it detects the return key? However this will still leave me with a problem, that is how to ignore the word Picture if it comes in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: It would likely be simpler to modify the Caption style to include Bold rather than to add direct formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following macro; it will process paragraphs beginning with either 'Picture' or 'Figure', applying Word's 'Strong' Style (a bold font) to them.

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^13[FP]i[gct]{1,2]ure [0-9]*^13"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found = True
    .Start = .Start + 1
    .Style = "Strong"
    .Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some modification of your code which searches from first to last. I also change the way you could select the whole sentence to mark it bold.

```
Sub Macro1()

     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

     With Selection.Find
         .Text = "figure"
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindStop
     End With

'changed the loop
     Do While Selection.Find.Execute
'changed the way we select sentence
        Selection.Expand wdSentence
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
     Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "Picture"
    .Replacement.Text = "Figure"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: The solution provided by macropod will execute more quickly because it is using range rather than selection.